# different html view by browser size(for mobile and for large display)

Tags: html, mobile, size

I want different templates in one html categorized by browser size.
not the same contents but with some additional or omitted information.
(like mobile-only browser)

ex) 
**computer**: no, category, title, user, date, hits; //
**mobile**: title, user, hits;

so I think @media in css is not the answer in this case.
is there any way to classify web by mobile and others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by toggling the html element's display attribute.
created two tables and make one display=none; and the other display=table; depending on window width.